# Lie group question: If $\gamma^{-1}\dot{\gamma}\in\mathfrak{g}$ everywhere, does $\gamma(t)\in G$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie subgroup of $GL(n,\Bbb R)$ and $\mathfrak{g}\subseteq M(n,\Bbb R)$ its Lie algebra. Suppose that we have a smooth curve
$$\gamma:\Bbb R\to G$$
with $\gamma(0)=I$. Then, it induces a curve on the Lie algebra
$$\alpha:\Bbb R\to \mathfrak{g},\quad \alpha(t)=\gamma(t)^{-1}\frac{d\gamma}{dt}(t).$$
I am wondering about the converse of this fact:

> **Question:** Let $\gamma:\Bbb R\to M(n,\Bbb R)$ be a smooth curve with $\gamma(0)=I$ and suppose that
>   $$\gamma(t)^{-1}\frac{d\gamma}{dt}(t)\in\mathfrak{g},\quad\forall t\in\Bbb R.$$
>   Does $\gamma(t)\in G$ for all $t\in\Bbb R$?

If true, it would have the following implication:

Let $\alpha:\Bbb R\to\mathfrak{g}$ be a smooth curve and consider the initial value problem
$$\frac{d\gamma}{dt}(t)=\gamma(t)\alpha(t),\quad \gamma(0)=I.$$
Since it is a first order linear system of ODEs, it has a unique solution
$$\gamma: \Bbb R\to M(n,\Bbb R),$$
and in fact $\gamma(t)\in G$ for all $t\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Actually, it's a much more general fact. Suppose I have a smooth manifold $M$ and a foliation on it: that is, a subbundle of the tangent bundle such that, at every point, there is locally a submanifold such that the subbundle is its tangent bundle. Then I can *integrate* the foliation to get a partition of my manifold into disjoint immersed submanifolds (which are also weakly embedded, if you know the term).

Then given a Lie subgroup of a Lie group $H$ (Lie subgroup meaning injective immersive homomorphism $G \to H$ from another Lie group), the tangent bundles of its cosets give a foliation of $H$. (The immersed submanifolds here are the cosets.)

I'm going to ignore the above formalism now, since it doesn't help you see the trees. If you like, you can see how the following argument ports over in general.

1) That $\gamma^{-1} \dot \gamma \in \mathfrak g$ is precisely the same thing as saying that $\gamma$ is tangent to the cosets of $G$ (precisely, $\gamma'(t)$ is tangent to the coset through $\gamma(t)$). We will show that, if $\gamma(t) \in G$, so is $\gamma(t+h)$, $h$ a small number (positive or negative). So around $\gamma(t)$, use the implicit function theorem to get a chart $U$ in which the inclusion of $G$ is just the map $\Bbb R^n \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^{n+k}$, and the inclusion of $hG$ for $h$ near $1$ is $\Bbb R^n \times {c} \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^{n+k}$. In this chart, your claim is just that if $\gamma(t) \in \Bbb R^n$, and $\dot \gamma \in \Bbb R^n$ (here we are using the special form of the chart, where orbits look like parallel copies of $\Bbb R^n$), then for all times $\gamma$ remains in the chart, $\gamma$ is in $\Bbb R^n$. But this is obvious - you can just integrate! This proves the desired theorem.

So the times for which $\gamma \in G$ forms an open set. But the times for which $\gamma \in hG$ (that is, for which $\gamma$ is in some specified coset) are also open by the exact same argument. So you've obtained a partition of $\Bbb R$ into disjoint open sets. This is only possible if only *one* of the open sets is nonempty; and $\gamma(0) \in G$, so $\gamma(t) \in G$ for all $t$.

Comment: The contrast between foliation-bundle-subbundle part and part where you locally straighten subgroup as submanifold is just "ah!" :) Thanks for an explanation!

Comment: Something here bothers me a bit: In the image that I have in mind, it is certainly possible that $\gamma(t) \notin G$ for some small $t>0$. If we identify a small part of $G$ inside $GL_n$ as $\Bbb R^n \times \{0\} \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^{n+k}$, then we have $\dot \gamma(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ but $\gamma(t) \notin \Bbb R^n$ so $\gamma(t)$ is not tangent to $G=\Bbb R^n \times \{0\}$, but to a copy of $G$ ($\Bbb R^n \times \{c\}$). Am I missing something? I am not claiming that your final conclusion that $\gamma(t) \in G$ is false...

Comment: All I am saying is that I do not understand your first sentence "$\gamma^{-1} \dot \gamma \in \mathfrak g$ is precisely the same thing as saying that γ is tangent to the subgroup $G$". It seems to me your argument "assumes the conclusion" in some sense. Or are you using some specific facts regarding foliations (flat charts or something?). I would appreicate any clarification or elaboration you can give.

Comment: Also, I wonder if it matters that we assumed here $\gamma^{-1} \dot \gamma \in \mathfrak g$ and not $\dot \gamma  \gamma^{-1} \in \mathfrak g$?

Comment: @AsafShachar Bear with me, I haven't thought about this answer in 3 years. The tangent space $T_e G \subset T_e H$ is $\mathfrak g \subset \mathfrak h$. To identify this with the tangent space $T_g G$, you apply the operator $L_{g^{-1}}$, left-multiplication by $g^{-1}$; this gives an isomorphism of pairs $(T_g H, T_g G) \to (\mathfrak h, \mathfrak g)$. All the same, if you want to identify the tangent space $T_h hG$ with $T_e G$, apply left mult by $h^{-1}$. When I write $\gamma^{-1}(t) \gamma'(t)$, I mean the element of $T_e H$ given by $dL_{\gamma^{-1}(t)}: T_{\gamma(t)} H \to T_e H$.

Comment: So suppose I have a curve $\gamma \in H$, with $\gamma(t)$ lying on the coset $\gamma(t) G$. So if $\gamma'(t) \in T_{\gamma(t)} \gamma(t) G$, which is precisely the claim that $\gamma'$ is tangent to the foliation at some point, the above comment says that after applying $dL_{\gamma(t)}^{-1}$, we arrive back at a vector in $\mathfrak g$; that is, because $dL_{\gamma(t)^{-1}}: (T_{\gamma(t)} H, T_{\gamma(t)} \gamma(t) G) \to (T_e H, T_e G)$ is an isomorphism, we find that $dL_{\gamma(t)^{-1}}(\dot \gamma) \in \mathfrak g$ if and only if $\dot \gamma \in T_{\gamma(t)} \gamma(t) G$, as desired.

Comment: This sort of argument shows more generally that if you have a principal bundle $G \to P \to X$ with connection, and you pass to the $H$-bundle $P \times_G H$, if $\gamma$ is a horizontal curve, then in fact $\gamma$ lies in one of the $P \times_G Hg$ leaves. In this special case, $X$ is a point.

Comment: "one of the $P \times_G Gh$ leaves"*