# Can every tangent vector be realized as an acceleration of a path with a given velocity?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, symmetry, connections

$\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}$
Let $M$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold. Fix $p \in M, v \in T_pM$. Define
$$
\mathcal{A}_v:=\{ w \in T_pM\,|\,\exists\alpha:(-\epsilon,\epsilon) \to M, \, \, \alpha(0)=p, \dot \alpha(0)=v, (\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial_t}}\dot \alpha)(0)=w\},
$$
where $\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial_t}}\dot \alpha$ is the covariant derivative along the path $\alpha$ w.r.t the Levi-Civita connection.

**Conjecture:** For every $v \in T_pM$, we have $\mathcal{A}_v=T_pM$.

**Question:** Is there a coordinate-free proof?

*A possible solution:*

Set $\gamma(t) = \exp_p(t(v + \frac{t}{2}w))$. Then $(\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial_t}}\dot \alpha)(0)=w$.
Here is [an attempt to find a coordinate-free proof of that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4445335/a-coordinate-free-computation-of-the-acceleration-of-exp-ptv-fract2w).

---

*A coordinate-based approach:*

If $\dot \alpha(t)=a^i(t)\partial_i( \alpha(t))$, then
$$
\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial_t}}\dot \alpha(0)=\dot a^i(0)\partial_i+a^i(0)a^j(0)\Gamma_{ij}^k\partial_k.
$$
Now the $a^i(0)$ are uniquely determined by requiring $v=\dot \alpha(0)=a^i(0)\partial_i$.

Since we can freely choose $\dot a^i(0)$, we can always arrange for $\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial_t}}\dot \alpha(0)$ to equal any given vector $w$, regardless of the value of $a^i(0)a^j(0)\Gamma_{ij}^k\partial_k$.

Comment: I think something like $\gamma(t) = \exp_p(t(v + \frac{t}{2}w))$ works, no?

Comment: Well, this might look promising on a first glance, but unfortunately it doesn't work universally on all manifolds: Take for instance $M=\text{SO}_n$, $p=Id$. Then the Riemannian exponential map is just the standard exponential map, and taking $\alpha(t)=\exp(vt+\tfrac12 wt^2),$ one gets $\dot \alpha(0)=v, \ddot \alpha(0)=v^2+w.$ (See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3056589/104576) So instead of $\ddot \alpha(0)=w$, we got $\ddot \alpha(0)=v^2+w$, which does not even have a reasonable interpretation for more general manifolds:

Comment: After all $v^2$ denotes the multiplication of $v$ with itself; this notion exists for matrices, but not for "general tangent vectors" on arbitrary manifolds having less structure.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think there is some error somewhere in your example since $v^2$ is not even skew symmetric (so it is not in the tangent space of $SO(n)$). This second order derivative seems not to be a Levi-Civita derivative (one has to project it onto the tangent space)

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right! I confused the extrinsic acceleration, as measured in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ with the intrinsic one in $SO(n)$. You are completely right. So now I wonder whether your guess is correct. (Indeed after projecting the extrinsic acceleration $v^2+w$ onto the tangent space of skew-symmetric matrices, one is left with $w$ as you wanted. So I wonder whether that is true in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In geodesic normal coordinates constructed at a point, the Christoffel symbols vanish there. This makes it easy to see that the answer to your question is always Yes