# A coordinate free computation of the acceleration of $ \exp_p(t(v + \frac{t}{2}w))$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, alternative-proof, geodesic, connections

$\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}$
Let $M$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold. Fix $p \in M, v,w \in T_pM$, and define
$\gamma(t) = \exp_p(t(v + \frac{t}{2}w))$.

**Is there a coordinate-free proof that $(\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\dot \gamma)(0)=w$? Even without using normal coordinates?**

An attempt using Jacobi Fields:

Define $f(s,t)=\exp_p(t(v+sw))$. Then $\gamma(t)=f(t/2,t)$, so
$$
\dot \gamma(t)=1/2\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(t/2,t)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t/2,t).
$$
Thus (If I am applying the chain rule correctly?)
$$
\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\dot \gamma (0)=1/2\big(1/2\frac{D}{\partial s}\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(0,0)+\frac{D}{\partial t}\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(0,0)\big)+1/2\frac{D}{\partial s}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(0,0)+\frac{D}{\partial t}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(0,0)=
$$
$$
1/2\big(1/2\frac{D}{\partial s}\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(0,0)+\dot J(0)\big)+1/2\frac{D}{\partial s}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(0,0),
$$
where $J(t)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(t,0)$ is the Jacobi field associated with the geodesic variation $f(s,t)$. We have $\dot J(0)=w$.

Thus, so far we obtained
$$\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\dot \gamma (0)=
w/2+1/4 \frac{D}{\partial s}\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(0,0)+1/2\frac{D}{\partial s}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(0,0).
$$
I am not sure how to proceed.

---

When using normal coordinates, this is easy: In these coordinates $\gamma(t)=tv+\frac{t^2}{2}w$, so
$$
\dot \gamma(t)=v+tw=(v^i+tw^i)\partial_i(\gamma(t)).
$$
Thus
$$
(\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\dot \gamma)(0)=w^i\partial_i(p)+v^i\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\partial_i(\gamma(t))=w^i\partial_i(p)=w,
$$
where we used the fact that
$$\big(
\nabla_{\dot \gamma(t)}\partial_i\big)(p)=0,
$$
which follows from the fact that the  Christoffel symbols of normal coordinates vanish at the origin. (after expanding $\dot \gamma(t)$ in terms of the coordinate vector fields).

Comment: The irony here is that it is easier to first consider the more abstract case. First, let $c(s)$ be unit speed geodesic. Let $\sigma(t)$ be a scalar function. Let $r(t) = c(\sigma(t))$. Now use the chain rule to differentiate this twice.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that this doesn't work here; $\gamma(t) = \exp_p(t(v + \frac{t}{2}w))$ is not of the form $c(\sigma(t))$ where $c(t)$ is a geodesic. Indeed, the "initial velocity" is changing with time, so $\gamma$ is not a reparameterization of any single geodesic.

Comment: Yes, you’re right. Will post new comment later.